# How to style aggregate rows in ui-grid 3.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid using grouping, and defining custom tree aggregation and finalizer functions, very similar to this tutorial:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/320_complex_grouping

I want to apply a style that will make each grouped row blue if it contains more rows that are "male" then "female", and red if the reverse is true. For example, in the tutorial the states Wyoming and Wisconsin would be blue, while West Virginia and Virginia would be red.

In ng-grid this could've been accomplished by defining an `aggregateRowTemplate` but that doesn't seem to be an option in uiGrid.

If anyone could provide a solution that would be amazing.